# Get records where timestamp column is from 2 months ago but not from 1 month ago

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query a MySQL database where a timestamp column called `CrashReceived` is from two months ago but not including records from 1 month agao.

The idea is what I have a count comparison so I can get the count of records from the last month and then compare the count to the previous month.

I'm therefore testing a query to retrieve all records where the column value is from 2 months ago but doesn't include records from 1 month ago.

Below is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT * FROM crash_info WHERE ProjectID='14720069' AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH < CrashReceived AND (CrashReceived <> NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```

But this is returning records that are include today and yesterday so not doing what I'm after.

Comment: @Strawberry he provided an SQL statement that is minimal enough to understand and reproduce the problem. Did you downvote just because of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field must be bigger than time - 2 month but smaller than time - 1 month.

```
CrashReceived > (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
AND CrashReceived <= (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

You should apply an index to the field `CrashReceived`.

Comment: Thanks that was the trick, always struggle with working those kind of things for some reason. Thanks for the suggestion on the index, definitely need it but thought of that :)

Comment: @Boardy no problem! You should also try out Ankit's answer and if you like give an upvote, using `BETWEEN` can simplify greathan&smaller than things.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **between** operator for this:

```
SELECT * FROM crash_info 
WHERE ProjectID='14720069' AND 
CrashReceived BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) AND (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH));
```